# How do I save my Xbox Live Profile to a USB drive?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I want to take my profile and save it to a removable USB drive. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

First you'll have to format the USB drive so that your 360 can use it to store data. [Here's a page on Xbox.com that walks you through the process](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/Pages/xbox-360/how-to/usb-flash-drive.aspx), but the basic steps are:

1. Plug in the flash drive
2. Go to **System Settings** under **My Xbox**
3. Select **Memory**, then select **USB Storage Device**
4. Choose whether you want to use the entire drive for Xbox storage (up to 16GB), or only a portion of the drive (leaving the rest for files from your PC or whatever)

Now that the drive is set up, you can move your profile to it:

1. From **Memory**, select your hard drive and then choose **Profiles**.
2. Select your profile, and copy it over to the USB drive.

If your goal is to be able to take the flash drive with you when you play elsewhere, you might also want to move your saved games over as well. I keep my Rock Band save data on my removable drive so I can use my characters and bands at my friend's house, for example.

Answer (score 1):

From the (now defunct) Amazon discussion boards:

> Plug the flash drive in, go to your
> system menu and then go to memory.
> Configure your flash drive to create
> an Xbox partition. Now your flash
> drive will read as a memory unit. Copy
> your gamertag over.
>
> Also, make sure that you've downloaded
> the latest Xbox system update to your
> Xbox so that the option to use a flash
> drive is enabled.