# Trying to play Dragon Age: Awakening on a 4GB Xbox 360 isn't working

Tags: dragon-age-origins-awakening

Okay so, I got the Ultimate Edition of DAO and when I try to install Awakening it gives me an error saying I need an Xbox 360 HD. I have a 4GB elite Xbox 360! Why is this game not working?

Comment: Halo Reach had this issue when it came out - http://www.joystiq.com/2010/09/15/halo-reach-co-op-requires-hard-drive-4gb-xbox-360-slims-have-t/ - but I thought it was resolved, and hadn't heard that other games suffered from this.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any recent answers, but it appears that the 4GB model doesn't have enough space for the install (one site lists 4.1 GB as the install size).

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/984880-dragon-age-origins-awakening/58596209 suggests you'll have issues with any game of the year editions.

http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/rpg/dragonage/show_msgs.php?pid=950918&topic_id=m-1-57112630 suggests using a USB device of some sort to install to (although it's not clear whether that will really work, and I personally install to my HD and use my USB drives for saves-only).

So, try a USB drive larger than 4 GB if you have one, otherwise you may not be able to do the install with your current drive.

Comment: I have a 8 GB flashdrive, how do I configure it to work with my Xbox 360?

Comment: @Elizbeth, the first part of [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25439/how-do-i-save-my-xbox-live-profile-to-a-usb-drive/25441#25441) should explain how to set up your flash drive for use with a 360.

Comment: @Elizbeth: Did the USB drive work?

Answer (score 3):

The flash drive does not work.

I have tried installing the game directly onto the USB (16 GB) and that did not work, so I read somewhere that you could try to install the game and the expansion on a friends larger Xbox, and then move it onto the flash drive after it has been installed on the console, but that did not work either. It must be played on the Xbox it was originally installed on.

You could

- get a large Xbox hard drive and then purchase each expansion pack individually via xbox live; or
- purchase the game for the computer
- purchase a larger Xbox.
- install hard drive from another Xbox onto the 4GB Xbox.

Comment: This is really a comment to the other answer, not an answer in itself.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I disagree. Looks like it still provides possible solutions even though it competes and directly addresses issues with the other answer.

Comment: @AnnaLear Fair. It's certainly better with the edit.